# How would I go about Optimizing this move row code by reducing calls to the server?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got this code to loop through each cell in Column A and check the cell value. If the value matches the if criteria it moves the entire row to the correct Sheet and then replaces the Column A cell with an X. This makes a call to the server for every cell and I'm curious if there is a way for me to optimize it similar to what google has documented as [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices). The Cache service is confusing me.

[Here is a copy of the spreadsheet I'm working on.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DNND1A5-UROw2IoIGtTCQc77CcTjsHkZzpm08xJEPwE/edit?usp=sharing) The code has a menu execution under Move Row.

```
function moveToQA() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var columnNumberToWatch = 1;
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("QA ");

  for( var i = 3; i >= 3; i++ ) {
    var cell = sheet.getRange(i,1);
    var cellValue = cell.getValue();
    if (cellValue == "Captures Sent " || cellValue == "QA In Progress " || cellValue == "Recapture Completed ") {
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
      cell.setValue("X");
    }
    else if (cellValue != "") {
      continue;
    }
    else if (cellValue == "" || cell == lastRow) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider posting your question at codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Get the entire range you're interested in and then iterate over it using JavaScript. This will drastically reduce the number of calls to the server and speed things up quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The code example below might help. I've simplified your code somewhat as the question was about Best Practice, or as google call it 'batch operations'. This involves using `getValues()` to pull all the data into a JavaScript array in one I/O. So all subsequent comparisons and assignments are performed on objects in memory, and are therefore fast. Similarily, one `setValues()` call is used to write the data out to the spreadsheet in one I/O. This is far more efficient than reading the contents one cell at a time.

```
function moveToQA() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("QA");
  var input_range = ss.getRange("A:A"); // Entire column
  var values_in = [], values_out = [];
  // getValues() pulls all the values into a multi-dimensional array in one hit.
  // This allows values to be processed in-memory.
  values_in = input_range.getValues();

  for( var i = 0; i < lastRow; i++ ) {
    var cellValue = values_in[i][0];
    if (cellValue === "X") {
      values_out.push(["Yes"]);
    } else {
      values_out.push(["No"]);;
    }
  }
  // Now write out the new values in one hit.
  var output_range = targetSheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow);
  output_range.setValues(values_out);  
}
```

The cache service doesn't really apply to your program. As the documentation says, this is to preserve information **between** script executions. A use case for this is a GAS script, published as a web app, that provides a simple lookup web service based upon the content of a spreadsheet. Rather than read the data from the spreadsheet every time the web service is called, the script first checks to see if the data is available from the Cache Service. If it isn't the spreadsheet data is read and stored in a cache for next time.